# Why is saveAll() only saving the last record?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a situation where, for external reasons, I have to directly save join records rather than saving them as part of a join. Here's what I mean:

- I have a `Firm` model whose data is pulled from an external source.
- I have a `County` model in my app database
- I have a `counties_firms` join table that I use to associate those external firms to counties.

Because of what lives where, I'm not editing a `Firm` model nor am I editing a `County` model. I'm really just editing the associations. I have a `Firm` model to encapsulate anything I need to do with Firm data and one of these methods is `Firm::saveCounties( $data )`. It:

- Accepts incoming data that includes the firm id and the county ids that should be associated.
- Deletes all existing join records for that county
- *Attempts* to save all of the new join records.

What I'm finding is that only the last county record is saved. Here's the incoming data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [firm_id] => 13
            [county_id] => 4fa16e24-a25c-4523-8a9e-7d1d147402e8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [firm_id] => 13
            [county_id] => 4fa16e27-ccd0-4f22-97da-7d1d147402e8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [firm_id] => 13
            [county_id] => 4fa16e4a-68f8-4fb1-95bb-7d1d147402e8
        )

)
```

Given that data, I'm creating an on-the-fly association between `Firm` and `CountiesFirm` and attempting to `$this->CountiesFirm->saveAll( $data )`.

As I mentioned, only the last of the 3 county associations in this example is getting saved. Any idea what I might be missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing a level in your array... it should look something more like this...

```
Array(
    'CountiesFirm' => array(
        [0] => Array
        (
            [firm_id] => 13
            [county_id] => 4fa16e24-a25c-4523-8a9e-7d1d147402e8
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [firm_id] => 13
            [county_id] => 4fa16e27-ccd0-4f22-97da-7d1d147402e8
        )
        [2] => Array
        (
            [firm_id] => 13
            [county_id] => 4fa16e4a-68f8-4fb1-95bb-7d1d147402e8
        )
    )
)
```

Try that and let me know you results

Answer (score 4):

Your array is fine. It seems the model is not clearing its id, you can try and add ['id'] => null to every record in your array to force model id clearing.

This worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much Stefan!  I was only doing a plain save, not needing to be that efficient, but could only get the last record into the database.  Setting the id to NULL makes it work perfectly.